# Is interface ever useful for a OO language which supports multiple inheritance?

Tags: oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I heard that interface is introduced as a way for making up that a object-oriented language doesn't support multiple inheritance but only single inheritance.

Is interface merely used for that purpose?

Is interface ever useful for a OO language which supports multiple inheritance?

Thanks.

Comment: That's the question haunting me since 2014(The time i knew about interfaces).

Comment: No, interfaces were not introduced just to overcome limitations of single inheritance languages. An interface is an *interface* - the way something interacts with the rest of the world. It's a specific contract that every implementing class has to fulfill. A close analogy is an API - you don't care whether a service "inherits" from one class or another as long as it provides the API it said it would

Comment: But still is it of some use if we can directly use the functions. And anyways we cannot define contracts by just supplying method signatures. :D Sincere apologies.

Comment: You mean, are the *functions* of some use, if you have the interface/contract? The *interface* is the primary contract, not the function. A class may have a method called `Foo()`. That doesn't mean it implements `ITaxService.Foo()`. It's something that just happens to have the same name as the contract's method. Nor do you care *what* implements this contract. As long as you get *anything* that implements the contract, you can use it

Answer (score 1):

The book "Design Patterns" strongly stresses the importance of interfaces and at the time it was written, C++ (with multiple inheritance) was the most popular OO language and Java didn't even exist yet. (The book was published a year before Java was released.)

> It's important to understand the difference between an object's *class* and its *type*.
>
> An object's class defines how the object is implemented... In contrast, an object's type only refers to its interface—the set of requests to which it can respond.
>
> ...
>
> It's easy to confuse these two concepts, because many languages don't make the distinction explicit.
>
> ...
>
> Many of the design patterns depend on this distinction.

This book coined the term "Program to an Interface, not an Implementation."